# Unifying the sum of two error functions.

Tags: probability, statistics, error-function

Let's propose you have the sum of two error functions:

$f(x) = \text{erf}(ax)+\text{erf(bx)}$

If you wanted to solve for x, you'd first unify them into a third function

$f(x) = \text{erf}(cx)$

Or something similar. How could you approach this problem?

Comment: There is no addition formula for the error function.  Would a general numeric procedure for approximating $x$ suffice?

Comment: It would certainly help.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{erf}{erf}$
To go from your first to your second equation, we want 
$$  \erf(a x) + \erf(b x) = \erf(c x)  \tag{1}\label{original}  $$
Ideally, we could construct a function $c(a,b)$, depending only on $a$ and $b$, that satisfies \ref{original}.  Let's see if that is possible.  Let's relax the equation to 
$$  \erf(a x) + \erf(b x) = \erf(c y)  $$
to which we will specialize $y = x$ later to recover solutions to \ref{original}.  Let's get an idea of what we are wading into.  We'll set $a = -1$, $b = -2$ and plot contours for various values of $x$ on the $cy$-plane, highlighting the points where $x = y$.

[image: c-y Contours corresponding to solutions]

There are a few takeaways from this plot:

- The range of $\erf$ is $[-1,1]$.  For there to be any solution at all, $x$ must be such that the left-hand side is in that range.  For the chosen $a$ and $b$ this means $-0.3265{\dots} \leq x \leq 0.3265{\dots}$.  In other words, there are many choices of $a$, $b$, and $x$ for which no choice of $c$ satisfies \ref{original}.
- We have fixed $a$ and $b$, but the points on the contours where $y = x$ do not have the same abscissae.  This means the function $c$ cannot be independent of $x$.  That is, $c(a,b)$ does not work, but $c(a,b,x)$ can.

The last point means that *a* valid way forward is to solve \ref{original} for $c$ and announce that we are done.
$$  c = \frac{\erf^{-1} \left( \erf(ax) + \erf(bx) \right)}{x}  \text{,}  $$
where we use the inverse error function, $\erf^{-1}$.  If you put this into $\ref{original}$ you quickly realize that this is not responsive to your core question, which is solving $f(x) = \erf(ax) + \erf(bx)$.

---

Since there is no hope of an addition formula for $\erf$, and you have given no hints on the structure of $f$, we have to go to generic numerical techniques for solving.  First, constrain ranges.  Since the range of $\erf$ is $[-1,1]$, the right-hand side of 
$$  f(x) = \erf(ax) + \erf(bx)  \label{eqn}\tag{2}  $$
lies in $[-2,2]$, and so must the left-hand side.  If you can solve 
$$  -2 \leq f(x) \leq 2  $$
you will get a set of intervals, each of which contains zero or more solutions in $x$.  (An interval need not contain a solution since we have made no attempt to get the left-hand and right-hand sides of \ref{eqn} to agree.)

If you cannot solve that inequality, then use normal calculus optimization techniques to partition the $x$ axis into intervals on which $f(x)$ is either increasing or decreasing.  For each turning point (where the graph switches from rising to falling or vice versa), check whether it is above, in, or below the band $[-2,2]$.  An interval with both endpoints above, or both endpoints below, cannot contain a solution.  This produces a collection of intervals in which there may be a solution to \ref{eqn}.

For each interval identified above, repeat the process for $f(x) - (\erf(ax) + \erf(bx))$ where now we keep intervals whose turning points (i.e., endpoints) have opposing sign, because the band we are interested in is $[0,0]$.  Each resulting interval is guaranteed to contain an $x$ satisfying \ref{eqn}.  Such an interval may contain more than one solution.

### Example

Let $f(x) = x^2$, so we study $x^2 = \erf(-x) + \erf(-2x)$.  We can readily solve $-2 \leq x^2 \leq 2$ -- we immediately know that any solution satsifies $-\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$.  The first derivative of $x^2 -( \erf(-x) + \erf(-2x))$ is $2x + \frac{2 e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }} + \frac{4 e^{-4 x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$.  Plotting that derivative over $[-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}]$, we see

[image: the derivative]

So there is one zero of that derivative.  Running bisection on the interval $[-\sqrt{2}, 0]$ (on which interval the graph shows the derivative is monotonically increasing), we find the zero of the first derivative is at $x = -0.6224{\dots}$.  We can check the derivative at test points on either side of this zero, or observe from the graph that $x^2 -( \erf(-x) + \erf(-2x))$ monotonically decreases to the left of this critical point and increases to the right.  Thus, we get two intervals for bisection, $[-\sqrt{2}, -0.6224]$ and $[-0.6224, \sqrt{2}]$.  (Pro tip: when feeding numerical endpoints to a binary search, actually use numbers very slightly past the endpoint to ensure that representation/quantization error doesn't inadvertently produce a smaller interval than intended.)    For the first interval, bisection finds the solution $x = -1.3970{\dots}$; for the second, $x = 0$.  (You may actually get a small deviation from zero on any particular run of a bisection.  For instance, my first, coarse run gave $x = 6.6{\dots} \times 10^{-21}$.  This is suspiciously close to a round number, so I re-ran it with a higher precision and accuracy goal, yielding ever more accurate approximations to zero.  So either zero is a solution or it is an astoundingly good approximation of a solution.)

Let's check those.  \begin{align*}
(-1.3970)^2 &= 1.9516{\dots}  \\
\erf(-(-1.3970)) + \erf(-2(-1.3970)) &= 1.9517{\dots}
\end{align*}
(Using arbitrary precision code, we can sharpen this to $x = -1.397\,045\,412\,320\,144\,210\,312\,866\,479\,771\,694$, which gives a discrepancy of $<10^{-33}$ between the left-hand and right-hand sides of \ref{eqn}.)  Also,\begin{align*}
(0)^2 &= 0  \\
\erf(-(0)) + \erf(-2(0)) &= 0
\end{align*}
From which, we see that our second approximate solution is exact.  Our method ensures that we have found all solutions, but also,

[image: left-hand side minus right-hand side, a deformed parabola opening upward]

shows that we have found both solutions and that we had the correct intervals in each step.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments and answer, you will need some numerical method for solving for $x$ the nonlinear equation
$$y=\text{erf}(a x)+\text{erf}(b x)$$

I shall consider the case where $a$ and $b$ are positive (the other situations being more complex).

The first point is to notice that $y$ is bounded by $2\text{erf}(a x)$ and $2\text{erf}(b x)$.

Now, to have bounds, we could use the simple approximation
$$\text{erf}(t)\approx \sqrt{1-\exp\Big(-\frac 4 {\pi}t^2 \Big)}$$ which makes the solution to be between
$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \sqrt{-\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{y^2}{4}\right)}{a^2}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  \sqrt{-\frac{\log \left(1-\frac{y^2}{4}\right)}{b^2}}$$

Start at the midpoint and use Newton method. Using for example $a=0.5$, $b=1.5$ and $y=1.2345$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.81835949 \\
 1 & 0.67741900 \\
 2 & 0.69292373 \\
 3 & 0.69314665 \\
 4 & 0.69314670
\end{array}
\right)$$
What we could also do is to expand as Taylor series
$$y=\frac{2 x (a+b)}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{2 x^3 \left(a^3+b^3\right)}{3 \sqrt{\pi
   }}+\frac{x^5 \left(a^5+b^5\right)}{5 \sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{x^7
   \left(a^7+b^7\right)}{21 \sqrt{\pi }}+O\left(x^9\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$x=t+\alpha t^3+\beta t^5+\gamma t^7+O\left(t^9\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad t=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2 (a+b)}y$$
$$\alpha=\frac{1}{3} \left(a^2-a b+b^2\right)$$
$$\beta=\frac{1}{30} \left(7 a^4-17 a^3 b+27 a^2 b^2-17 a b^3+7 b^4\right)$$
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{630} \left(127 a^6-519 a^5 b+1191 a^4 b^2-1471 a^3 b^3+1191 a^2 b^4-519 a b^5+127 b^6\right)$$
For the worked example, this would give, as an *estimate* to start with, $x=0.685654$.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the substitution for determining the bounds? And more details about the approximation? There is a similar but much more complicated approximation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations) but not this one.

Comment: @user19087 : *"The first point is to notice that $y$ is bounded by $2\text{erf}(a x)$ and $2\text{erf}(b x)$."* Now, which approximation ?

Comment: The approximation $\operatorname{erf}(t) \approx \sqrt{1-\exp\left(-\frac{4}{\pi}t^2\right)}$. I have questions and comments, many of each.

Comment: Let's call the $\operatorname{erf}$ approx. $\operatorname{aerf}$. Ideally, solve $y=\operatorname{aerf}(ax)+\operatorname{aerf}(bx)$ for $x$, but that's difficult or impossible even though $\operatorname{aerf}$ has a closed form unlike $\operatorname{erf}$. Instead find $y_1$ and $y_2$ such that $y_1<y<y_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ can each be solved for $x$. You picked $2\operatorname{aerf}(ax)$ and $2\operatorname{aerf}(bx)$. This is my most important question. How do you determine the boundary functions for a sum of $a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$ where $b$ is always positive or always negative?

Comment: Boundary functions provide a range for possible values of $y$. Your argument depends on (1): $y_1 < y < y_2$ implying $y_1^{-1} < y^{-1} < y_2^{-1}$ when y is decreasing and $y_2^{-1} < y^{-1} < y_1^{-1}$ when y is decreasing. You use this to provide a range in $x$ for $y$ and use this range to find the initial midpoint. Given $y = \sum a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$, $y$ is strictly increasing when $b > 0$, and strictly decreasing when $b < 0$. Does (1) hold when $b$ is mixed negative and positive? While intuitive, is there even a proof of (1) for monotonic functions?

Comment: Next I want to note that $\operatorname{aerf}(t)$ is equivalent to $\lvert \operatorname{erf}(t) \rvert$. Solutions of $\operatorname{aerf}(t)$ for $t$ are of the form $\pm \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sqrt{-log \left(1 - t^2 \right)}$, $+$ when $y>0$ and $-$ when $y<0$. Also the boundary functions flip at $x=0$. Given $a=0.5,b=1.5$ then $\operatorname{erf}(ax)$ is the upper bound when $x<0$ and the lower bound when $x>0$. And $\operatorname{erf}(bx)$ is the lower bound when $x<0$ and the lower bound when $x>0$. If $y$ is unknown, there are two solutions: $[a,b]$ and $[-b,-a]$.

Comment: The general case is $f(x) = \sum a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$ where $c$ represents shifts along $x$. We only consider the case when $b$ is either always positive or always negative. For the approximation function $\operatorname{aerf}(x)$, this must hold for all $x$: $\operatorname{sgn}(f) = \operatorname{sgn}(\operatorname{aerf})$. Because $\operatorname{aerf}(x) \approx \lvert \operatorname{erf}(t) \rvert$, if the signs don't match there may be intervals where the boundary functions do not provide upper or lower bounds.

Comment: When you use Newton's method, do you use an approximation of $\operatorname{erf}$ that is more accurate? Because series reversion only provides an approximate solution, I assume it is intended to be followed by Newton's method, i.e. series reversion provides only the initial midpoint?

Comment: What is the series reversion for the general case $y = \sum a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$ when $b$ is either always positive or always negative? I can tell that it must be very complicated, however I am forced to it as I do not have a general method for deriving bounds and difficulties with boundary conditions using $\operatorname{aerf}$. Since $y$ is infinitely differentiable, I suggest using instead Lagrange inversion. What do you think about this?

Comment: I must retract that. Lagrange inversion of $y = \sum a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$ is feasible because the point $(0,0)$ exists. Though unnecessary as there is a [simple formula](https://www2.newpaltz.edu/~dominicd/NESTED14.pdf) for the reversion coefficients in such a case. For $y = \sum a\cdot\operatorname{erf}(bx+c)$ Lagrange inversion is intractable.